# Cocoa - Storing Time

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a date picker which shows just the time, "00:00". Do I need to save this as a date or is there a better way?

If as a date, should I use something like 01/01/2000 05:45 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just the time that you care about and you never need to deal with timezones or other adjustments, you can store your time as "seconds since midnight". This only works if your times are always "local" time.

But since `UIDatePicker` will give you time as an `NSDate` (the date portion will default to "today") and since you can easily use an `NSDateFormatter` to display just the time portion, you may wish to stick with `NSDate`.

But using `NSDate` can be a problem for sorting since the sorting of the dates will also include the date portion. You also need to consider how you plan to persist the values.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you want to store. Here is code to separate date and time.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterDateOnly = nil;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterTimeOnly = nil;
NSString *tempdateStringDateOnly = @"";
NSString *tempdateStringTimeOnly= @"";
if (dateFormatterDateOnly == nil) {
    dateFormatterDateOnly = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatterDateOnly setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
}
if (dateFormatterTimeOnly == nil) {
    dateFormatterTimeOnly = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatterTimeOnly setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
}

tempdateStringDateOnly  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dateFormatterDateOnly stringFromDate:selectedDate]];   
tempdateStringTimeOnly  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dateFormatterTimeOnly stringFromDate:selectedDate]];
```